How to use an externally declared variable within a python exe file (PyInstaller)?
I am using the software of a laboratory device to create methods on this device. The software allows me to run .exe files and also provides the option to pass information in form of variables into said .exe files.
I've managed to execute the most basic programs created with Python and PyInstaller and now I am wondering how I can make use of the data passed in by the lab software within my python code.
Is there a statement like import or get that lets me use the content of the content of the variables and, additionally, with what statement would I define the return value of the exe file
What I am expecting is something like this
Lab device software:
#var1# = "Hello"

Run ..\app.exe #var1#, and wait for completion. Save result code to ReturnValue
App.py (transformed into an .exe file):
import/get var1

return_value = var1 + "World"

export/return return_value


Does this answer your question? How can I read and process (parse) command line arguments?

It does for the first part. Do you know how to return values as well? Thank you so much

Which  laboratory device are you using? The manufacturer might have some examples available.

What do you mean by "return values", just print to the terminal standard output or something else?

The device is the liquid handler "Lynx" from dynamic devices and it's using the MethodManager4 as software. I am getting in touch with them directly for a solution.
By return value I mean, that the device software has an input field, where I can point to a method variable (within Method Manager), which contains the "response code" of the exe file.
